# Taking screenshot works in simulator but fails on real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have the following code that takes a screenshot of the game screen then shares it when the "share" button is tapped.

It works great on simulator and returns the correct image. However, on my real device, it returns a white image. Every time.

Here is the code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let Touch : UITouch! = touches.first
    let TouchLocation = Touch.location(in: self)

    if let body = self.physicsWorld.body(at: TouchLocation){

        if body.node!.name == "shareButton" {
                let postText: String = "Check out my score! Can you beat it?"
                let postImage: UIImage = getScreenshot()
                let activityItems = [postText as AnyObject, postImage] //as [Any]
                let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
                    activityItems: activityItems,
                    applicationActivities: nil
                )

                let controller: UIViewController = scene!.view!.window!.rootViewController!

                controller.present(
                    activityController,
                    animated: true,
                    completion: nil
                )
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the function:

```
func getScreenshot() -> UIImage {
    let snapshotView = self.view!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)

    snapshotView?.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let screenshotImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return screenshotImage;
}
```

I narrowed down my problem to these lines of code:

```
let postText: String = "Check out my score! Can you beat it?"
let postImage: UIImage = getScreenshot()
let activityItems = [postText as AnyObject, postImage] //as [Any]
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: activityItems,
    applicationActivities: nil
)

let controller: UIViewController = scene!.view!.window!.rootViewController!

controller.present(
    activityController,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil
)

func getScreenshot() -> UIImage {
    let snapshotView = self.view!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)

    snapshotView?.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let screenshotImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return screenshotImage;
}
```

Please note that I only use one class. This one:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
}
```

I narrowed it down by creating a new app. I changed nothing to the default Hello World app except adding those lines of code. They return the same result: Blank image.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: is sim and device same ios version?

Comment: Sim is 10.3, Device is 10.3.1

Comment: this is perplexing... ive had similar issues but only when device was older or newer than sim. only thing i van suggest is to create new xcode project, and try a second device

Comment: Tried a 10.0 device. Same result: Blank screenshot.

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's reply, we've no way to do so for security reasons.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/108278?answerId=613818022#613818022

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use for taking a screenshot.  The big difference is I have false where you have true for afterScreenUpdates:

```
public extension UIView {
    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return snapshotImage
    }

    public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
        if let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() {
            return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```